# "A fear of something" vs "fear of something"

Tags: articles, countability

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fear), the word "fear" is both countable and uncountable. So, when referring to the fear of flying, can I say:

> I have fear (uncountable) of flying?

Answer (score 3):

> a fear of flying

is one kind of fear. Since this is one of many types (fear of heights, fear of closed spaces, etc.), it is countable in your context.
*fear* in the case of feelings might be uncountable.

> When the roller coaster went upside down, I was filled with **fear**.

Comment: But, the part " of flight" makes the noun more specific. Can't we say "the fear of flight"?